# How to implement sorting in namespace extension using shell folder defview

Tags: winapi, sorting, explorer, windows-shell, shell-extensions

I have a working namespace extension using ATL/MFC. To make it look like explorer I used the default shell folder view (defview) using SHCreateShellFolderView. So far everything works pretty well. Only big question mark I have is how I can implement sorting in the defview when a column is clicked? When I click on a column CompareIDs of the IShellFolder is called but I have to set focus into the view and hit F5 to see some changes. I tried searching the internet but information on this subject is pretty rare...

Kind regards,
Michael

Answer (score 1):

Maybe response to the [SFVM_COLUMNCLICK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774209%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message helps you.

Example:

```
HRESULT ExampleFolderView_OnColumnClick(HWND hwnd, UINT uiColumn)
{
    SHShellFolderView_Message(hwnd, SFVM_REARRANGE, uiColumn)
    return S_OK;
}
```